# Sqlite data to NSMutableArray Error

Tags: iphone, ios, c, arrays

I'm trying to do a small class to manage Sqlite. I want to store the data retrieved from the DB into an array of objects but get app crashed (BAD_ACCESS)

My code:

```
- (ArrayList *) execNonQuery: (char *) query {
    @try {
        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStat;
        ArrayList *dataList;

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(self->dbHandle, query, -1, &sqlStat, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            dataList = [[ArrayList alloc] init];

            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStat) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                NSMutableArray *list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

                for (int i = 0; i < sqlite3_column_count(sqlStat); i++) {
                    // CRASH
                    id data = (__bridge id)(sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, i)); 

                    [list addObject: data]; 
                }

                [dataList addList:list];
            }
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStat);

        return dataList;
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Excepción capturada: %@", [exception reason]);

        return NULL;
    }
}
```

I think the problem is when i try to do:

```
id data = (__bridge id)(sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, i));
```

**Note:** The ArrayList Class is just NSMutableArray of NSMutableArray

Im noob in objective c, just learning... and sorry for spelling errors.

Best regards.

Comment: `@try @catch` is not a good programing schee to use, whichever language you are using.

Comment: seems like you got nil in your 'id data'. you can not add nil value to NSMutableArray

Comment: where exactly its crashing?

Comment: Thanks Puneeth but still crashing...

Comment: it looks like the problem is id data = (__bridge id)(sqlite3_column_value(sqlStat, i)); but i dont know why.

Comment: I tried with sqlite3_column_text and works fine but with sqlite3_column_value is crashed. Why ?

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa: The problem is that `sqlite3_column_value()` returns a  pointer to a `sqlite3_value`, and you cannot just cast that to `id` (which is a pointer to an Objective-C object).

Comment: You are right Martin R, thanks you very much. So, how can i cast the sqlite3_value to id? Because i need to store the data in nssmutablearray array as id and non specific datatype.

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa: I don't know exactly what sqlite3_value contains. But perhaps have a look at NSValue, which can wrap C-structs into an Objective-C object, which then can be added to an NSArray.

Comment: @SamuelPedrosa: If you solved the problem, please add an answer with the solution.

Comment: Not fully resolved, only now I know where fails with your help :)

Comment: sqlite3_column_value returns a [sqlite3_value structure](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/value.html), which is not an Objective-C object.  You *cannot* (validly) cast it to `id`.  You are advised to use the [type-appropriate return function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html): sqlite3_column_int, sqlite3_column_text, etc.

Comment: You do have the [SQLite documenation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/intro.html) bookmarked, right?

Comment: "Because i need to store the data in nssmutablearray array as id and non specific datatype." Store it as `id`, use NSString, NSNumber, et al, and you've accomplished that.